# Disposed method in ICollection over an Array

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, dispose, icollection

So I have created ICollection wrapper class over an array:

```
public class Product { public string name; }

Public class ProductCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : Product
{
    T[] dataCollection;
    
    public void Add(T item){...}
    public void Clear(T item){...}
    public void Containers(T item){...}
    public void CopyTo(T item){...}

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return new Enumerator<T>(this); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return new Enumerator<T>(this); }
}

class Enumerator<B> : IEnumerator<B> where B : Product
{
    B[] collection;

    public Enumerator(ProductCollection<B> collection)
    {
       this.collection = collection.dataCollection;
    }

    public B current...
    public bool MoveNext()...
    public void Reset()...

    public void Dispose()
    {
       ????
    }

}
```

Is the Dispose method required here since the Product class does not contain any unmanaged resources only a string property?

Comment: Even if the `Product` class *was* disposable, you still shouldn't be disposing those elements in the enumerator class, because it doesn't OWN the collection. The dispose in an enumerator relates to the enumeration code, in case it created anything that should be disposed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're manually implementing the enumerator rather than just deferring to the wrapped array or (if some code needs to run) just writing an iterator?

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning experience? In typical programming scenarios there is little reason nowadays in .NET to write your own custom enumerators and typically collection types.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just for the code expression simplifiction - I would normally need to do it this way: `ProductCollection<Product> Collection = new ProductCollection<Product>() {product1, product2, product2) foreach (Product P in ProductCollection.Products)...`
but I can do it `foreach(Product P in ProductCollection)`

Comment: @Ttech - you don't seem to have understood my question. I was asking why you don't simply have `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return dataCollection.GetEnumerator();}`, as the simplest example?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>'
I could use this implementation in `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` though

Answer (score 2):

> Is the Dispose method required here since the Product class does not contain any unmanaged resources only a string property?

Yes, you need a dispose method since `IEnumerator<T>` derives from IDisposable. But it is fine to leave the dispose method empty if there is no resources to dispose of.

But instead of writing your own Enumerator you should probably just use the one provided by the underlying array: `((IEnumerable<T>)datacollection).GetEnumerator();`. If you need to do something special you could use an [iterator block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators). Even better would be to just use a `List<Product>` instead of writing your own custom collection, there should rarely be any need to write a custom collection class.